# Does Puppeteer run JavaScript on the page?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer for some testing tasks, and am a bit confused:
Does Puppeteer run the JavaScript it encounters? Specifically, our app fires of a bunch of requests (eg. loading Stripe, Facebook, etc), and I want to ensure that code is being run during a Puppeteer request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does Puppeteer run JavaScript on the page?

**Yes, it does.**

> Does Puppeteer run the JavaScript it encounters?

**Yes, it does.**

JavaScript is enabled by default:

<sub>While Puppeteer's documentation does not explicitly say that JavaScript is enabled by default, [their tutorial documentation does say that it launches Chrome in headless mode by default](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/get-started#default_runtime_settings), and [Chrome's headless mode has JavaScript enabled by default](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome), therefore Puppeteer has JavaScript enabled by default).</sub>

You can enable or disable it with `page.setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean): Promise<void>`

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pagesetjavascriptenabledenabled

You can check if it is enabled with `page.isJavaScriptEnabled(): boolean`

---

> Specifically, our app fires of a bunch of requests (eg. loading Stripe, Facebook, etc), and I want to ensure that code is being run during a Puppeteer request.

[Use Puppeteer's Code Coverage feature](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-class-coverage) to test that your JavaScript is actually executed, including the lines and functions you want to run.

[This (unrelated) blog page has an example](https://nitayneeman.com/posts/getting-to-know-puppeteer-using-practical-examples/#code-coverage).